# What is needed for Spring to be installed?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have IntelliJ IDEA 11 and I added the Spring facet (checking all boxes) so now I have a lot of libraries in the module. However, is this all I need? Does Spring depend on Java EE 6 implementations such as Glassfish or JBoss? Or is Spring all I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is not Java EE; Spring (and its dependencies) are all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has its own and better alternatives to EJB and can run tomcat because injection and jta  can be handled by spring.So you only need to add spring jars to your class path.

Comment: I'd argue that it's no longer the "obvious" choice as a JEE replacement since the introduction of JEE 6, which is really quite nice. It's still a great option (I use Spring quite frequently), but it's no longer a cut-and-dry decision.